# How to select random value from readonly datepicker in jmeter?

Tags: datepicker, jmeter, readonly

We have a **readonly** **datepicker** which shows date from specific date/month/year **(dd/mm/yyyy)** format. Now since its readonly, passing input is not possible. How can we select date from datepicker?

Above requirement has simple form to submit.

Comment: Is it in a webdriver tests? In the request you can simply make use of the time function: https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__time

Comment: no, thats not useful in above case. we have date picker which is readonly and only option is to select date from date picker

Comment: Please share your webdriver code and the HTML element

Comment: its jmeter,not web driver

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [Post-Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) in order to extract the value from the HTML code of the response and store it into a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)

The most suitable Post-Processor for HTML is [CSS Selector Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-cssjquery-extractor-jmeter), you can use [CSS Selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) in order to access "interesting" parts of the response.

Here is the demo of fetching date from the input assuming `CSS Selector Tester` mode of the [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener:

[image]

Comment: thank you. I think you mis understood my query. We have to click on date picker and select date, selected date will become readonly.